# App does not install in android version 7

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I have an app that is in the play store and everyone can install it up to version 6 of the android. But people with version 7 of android are not able to install.

[Can not install app - error code -504](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRBcj.jpg)

My build.gradle (Module:app) is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "net.ayurvedese.ayurvedese"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 7
        versionName "1.5"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile files('libs/ksoap2-android-assembly-3.5.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.1.6'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Could anyone tell me what could be happening?

Comment: You may wish to provide an English translation of the error seen on Android 7.  And maybe some more info on the app itself, e.g., name, what it does.

Comment: Have you tried installing it yourself (e.g., via `adb install`) on an Android 7.0 device or emulator? BTW, you really need to synchronize those support library versions (don't use 25.2.0 for one and 25.0.0 for the others).

Comment: @CommonsWare yes! The instalation in my Android phone it´s ok. I did the synchronization of the support libraries versions (both for 25.0.0)

Comment: @CaptainBli the english translation of the error is: "Unable to install app
Can not install 'Ayurvedese'. Try again. If the problem persists, try troubleshooting. (Error code: -504)"

Comment: "The instalation in my Android phone it´s ok" -- can you try installing it from the Play Store on that device?

Comment: @CommonsWare i published a new version of the app in the play store and still the error persists.